# Text Length and Setting Up a Tooltip

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Say I have a text populating either a Label or a Datagrid in my C# WPF application which is setup for a fixed width (the fixed width will vary from control to control). These controls are being populating via stored procedures. Now I would like to have a tooltip to display the contents of the control on a mouse over, which I can do, but only when the text context is greater then the width of the control, which I don't know how to do.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Post the relevant XAML.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264398/how-to-calculate-wpf-textblock-width-for-its-known-font-size-and-characters 
this is not a full answer but it's a way of calculating the inner string

Comment: Hard to post XAML when I am asking how to do something before attempting to do it.... Thanks for the link, will look