# GMAP.NET adding labels underneath markers

Tags: winforms, gmap.net

I have just started using gmap.net and I was looking for the functionality of adding labels under the markers. I see there's tooltips but I would like to have a constant label under my marker with a one word description.

I searched for docs or other answers but I cannot find anything which leads me to believe that it is not implemented. If someone can verify this I would appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms?

Comment: @rdoubleui Windows Forms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create your own custom marker.

Based on the source of [GMapMarker](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GMap.NET.WindowsForms/GMap.NET.WindowsForms/GMapMarker.cs) and the derived [GMarkerGoogle](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GMap.NET.WindowsForms/GMap.NET.WindowsForms/Markers/GMarkerGoogle.cs) I came up with this simplified example:

```
public class GmapMarkerWithLabel : GMapMarker, ISerializable
{
    private Font font;
    private GMarkerGoogle innerMarker;

    public string Caption;

    public GmapMarkerWithLabel(PointLatLng p, string caption, GMarkerGoogleType type)
        : base(p)
    {
        font = new Font("Arial", 14);
        innerMarker = new GMarkerGoogle(p, type);

        Caption = caption;
    }

    public override void OnRender(Graphics g)
    {
        if (innerMarker != null)
        {
            innerMarker.OnRender(g);    
        }

        g.DrawString(Caption, font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(0.0f, innerMarker.Size.Height));
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        if(innerMarker != null)
        {
            innerMarker.Dispose();
            innerMarker = null;
        }

        base.Dispose();
    }

    #region ISerializable Members

    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);
    }

    protected GmapMarkerWithLabel(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Usage (assuming a `GMap` instance named `gm`):

```
GMapOverlay markerOverlay = new GMapOverlay("markers");
gm.Overlays.Add(markerOverlay);

var labelMarker = new GmapMarkerWithLabel(new PointLatLng(53.3, 9), "caption text", GMarkerGoogleType.blue);
markerOverlay.Markers.Add(labelMarker)
```

Comment: Pretty sure it's a similar approach, could add a sample later if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer here because this is the first question that pops up when looking to display a text marker for the **WPF** GMAP.NET library. Displaying a text marker with the WPF version of the library is actually much easier than in WinForms, or at least than the accepted answer.

The `GMapMarker` in WPF has a `Shape` property of type `UIElement`, which means you can provide a `System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock` object to display a text marker :

```
Markers.Add(new GMapMarker(new PointLatLng(latitude, longitude))
{
    Shape = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock(new System.Windows.Documents.Run("Label"))
});
```

Since the marker displays the top left portion of the shape at the given position, you can play with the `GMapMarker.Offset` property to adjust the text position according to its dimensions. For instance, if you want the text to be horizontally centered on the marker's position :

```
var textBlock = new TextBlock(new Run("Label"));
textBlock.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
textBlock.Arrange(new Rect(textBlock.DesiredSize));
Markers.Add(new GMapMarker(new PointLatLng(request.Latitude, request.Longitude))
{
    Offset = new Point(-textBlock.ActualWidth / 2, 0),
    Shape = textBlock
});
```

The solution to get the `TextBlock`'s dimensions was quickly taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264398/how-to-calculate-wpf-textblock-width-for-its-known-font-size-and-characters), so if you need a more accurate way of getting the block's dimensions to play with the offset I suggest you start from there.