# GMAP.NET, adding labels to markers

Tags: winforms, google-maps, label, marker

I am using GMAPS in C# (Winforms) and I would like to add a marker with a label. I followed the answer at [GMAP.NET adding labels underneath markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057534/gmap-net-adding-labels-underneath-markers) and noticed that there is an issue with the implementation. The markers are not plotted in the correct place and the labels are all plotted on top of each other. I think it is not correctly calling the OnRender method for the marker? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Sounds like a bug that was fixed several years ago

Comment: Interesting, as far as I can tell I'm using the latest version (1.7.1). I managed to fix the marker placement issue by calling base.OnRender(g).

Answer (score 1):

In ran into the same issue and just calling `base.OnRender(g);` wasn't fixing it for me. The trick is to derive from `GMarkerGoogle` instead of `GMapMarker` as done in the answer you provided.

Also I had to do some tweaks with the text rendering. I came up with this solutions, works fine for me:

```
public class GmapMarkerWithLabel : GMarkerGoogle, ISerializable
{
    private readonly Font _font;
    private GMarkerGoogle _innerMarker;
    private readonly string _caption;

    public GmapMarkerWithLabel(PointLatLng p, string caption, GMarkerGoogleType type)
        : base(p, type)
    {
        _font = new Font("Arial", 11);
        _innerMarker = new GMarkerGoogle(p, type);

        _caption = caption;
    }

    public override void OnRender(Graphics g)
    {
        base.OnRender(g);

        var stringSize = g.MeasureString(_caption, _font);
        var localPoint = new PointF(LocalPosition.X - stringSize.Width / 2, LocalPosition.Y + stringSize.Height);
        g.DrawString(_caption, _font, Brushes.Black, localPoint);
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        if (_innerMarker != null)
        {
            _innerMarker.Dispose();
            _innerMarker = null;
        }

        base.Dispose();
    }

    #region ISerializable Members

    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        GetObjectData(info, context);
    }

    protected GmapMarkerWithLabel(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    { }

    #endregion
}
```