# Auto ToolTip on TextBlock trimming

Tags: wpf, tooltip, textblock, trim, texttrimming

I have tried everything,

solution1: https://siderite.dev/blog/determining-if-textblock-has-been.html

solution2: http://blog.scottlogic.com/2011/01/31/automatically-showing-tooltips-on-a-trimmed-textblock-silverlight-wpf.html

My solution:

```
<TextBlock.ToolTip> 
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ToolTipVisibilityWhenTextTrimmedConverter}">                                 
       <Binding ElementName="mytextblock" Path="Text"/>
       <Binding ElementName="mytextblock"/>
       <Binding ElementName="mytextblock" Path="MaxWidth"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.ToolTip>
```

and

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var text = values[0];
    TextBlock tb = (TextBlock)values[1];
    var maxwidth = values[2];
    var result = CommonMethods.MeasureString(tb);
    bool isTextTrimmed = result.Width > (double)maxwidth;
    var retval = (isTextTrimmed) ? text : null;

    return retval;
}
```

But still when the `TextBlock` width is very close to get trimmed the `ToolTip` is shown. Sometimes when the last 2 characters are trimmed the `ToolTip` is not shown.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's in your `CommonMethods.MeasureString`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264398/how-to-calculate-wpf-textblock-width-for-its-known-font-size-and-characters  

I use the formattedText  to calculate the size the TextBlock's Text

 var formattedText = new FormattedText(
        candidate,
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture,
        FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
        new Typeface(this.textBlock.FontFamily, this.textBlock.FontStyle, this.textBlock.FontWeight, this.textBlock.FontStretch),
        this.textBlock.FontSize,
        Brushes.Black);