# UWP - Canvas - TextBoxes overlap even though math is correct

Tags: uwp

In a canvas, I layout my controls myself through code. I use **SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty)**,**SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)**, **Width** and **Height** properties. I give a default height as 24 and 2 textboxes that should be rendered on top of each other seems overlapping. When I set the height to 30, this doesn't happen and textboxes render on top of each other correctly. I was thinking that maybe UWP assumes textbox height to be some minimum value more than 24 and extends it anyway. Does UWP assume a minimum textbox height or what might be happening in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `TextBox` has a `MinHeight` of 32 as defined by the default style via the `TextControlThemeMinHeight` ThemeResource.

You can easily find that by inspecting the application at runtime with the Live Visual Tree and Live Property Explorer in Visual Studio

*when you set the Height to 30, you don't notice overlapping because of the padding (10,3,6,5) and border thickness (2).

Comment: I see. I have one more question. I have to calculate the size of string with a certain font size and family. I use TextBlock, and set all properties like font, etc. Then I call Measure method of the TextBlock and then read DesiredSize property to determine how much space I should allocate on the canvas for TextBlock with certain string. Desired size comes out wrong.

Comment: That's a separate question. Seems like it's been answered already - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969056/how-can-i-measure-the-text-size-in-uwp-apps

Comment: That's exactly what I do, but that question's answer doesn't work for me.