# Get char widths

Tags: c#, wpf

In my app I write some text to word document, I have a textbox in the app that I want to limit the number of characters in it according to the character widths.

In the begining I limited the number of characters, but the I figured that not all characters have the same width,
I mean, if the user enters `fffff`, it's not the same width as `wwwww`

I need something like:

```
if(someString.Width>15.5)
  //do stuff
```

Comment: Which framework ? Winforms/WPF?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten WPF

Comment: I would guess that this is entirely dependent on the font. Maybe you should just use a monospace font and not have to worry about it.

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264398/how-to-calculate-wpf-textblock-width-for-its-known-font-size-and-characters)