# way to determin the length of text based on the font, the font size, and characters in the text

Tags: c#, winforms

The requirement is the length of a text on the screen cannot exceed a certain length.  But it all depends on the font type, the size and of course characters in it.  Some characters such as i and l and skinnier than say M, W, and Q.

So is there a way to measure the length programmatically?  I am trying to accomplish this in the windows desktop environment, not on the web.

Comment: This is a global issue where you cannot restrict the length of a sentence with respect to screen because the size of each alphabet is different. I am afraid you cannot resolve it. You have to find a workaround for it. The workaround is to divide your screen in small columns of same width (same as width of biggest alphabet, say W) and then restrict the length.

Comment: MeasureText, System.Drawing? This has to be a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine Label Size based upon amount of text and font size in Winforms/C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388937/determine-label-size-based-upon-amount-of-text-and-font-size-in-winforms-c)

Comment: or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/721168/265419)